# Cookie - Why cookie showing in browser after it deleted by using PHP code

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

Why cookie values showing in browser even after it deleted by using PHP code, I am viewing cookie values by using FireFox "View Cookies addon". It will disappear only after delete or clear my browser cookies manually. I asking this question because of my work will work only after deleting cookies from browser manually, if i unset cookie in PHP code and run , it will not work, i am un setting cookie value by setting its expire date with past value.Example:

```
setcookie ("myCookie", "", time() - 3600, "/", ".example.com");
```

Code I am using for setting cookie:

```
setcookie ('Event', '', time() - 3600, '/', '.example.com');
```

Code I am using for unsetting cookie:

```
setcookie('Event', '-1-1301223453%7C9de8f7c08bf2be19c125f86ced33a0c2%7C1301050653%7C-1%7C1301223453', '', '/', '.example.com', 0);
```

But if i print cookie value after it unset it will be blank(nothing), but it will show in browser

Please any one help!!

Comment: show us the code you use to unset the cookie as well as set it.

Comment: Have you checked your system time?

Comment: Thnks for reply!!. Code I am using for setting cookie:

    setcookie ('Event', '', time() - 3600, '/', '.example.com');
Code I am using for unsetting cookie:

    setcookie('Event', '-1-1301223453%7C9de8f7c08bf2be19c125f86ced33a0c2%7C1301050653%7C-1%7C1301223453', '', '/', '.example.com', 0);

But if i print cookie value after it unset it will be blank(nothing), but it will show in browser

Answer (score 2):

That is completely based on browser settings you are viewing in and you are asking that the browser is still showing the cookies. That is true browser is still showing the cookies but you will get relax when you check it in PHP the cookie is unset.

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

show you the active cookies.

Remember when you clear cookies from your browser tool then cookie will be erased but when you unset from the PHP they are set to the time in past not erased from browser history.

Comment: Thanks for reply!!!. If i print cookie value after it unset it will be blank(nothing), but my work will working fine after it deleting from browser, can you suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Delete cookie with `setcookie("myCookie");`

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this approach?

```
// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: According to php.net: If cookie names are in Array notation, eg: user[username] 
Then PHP will automatically create a corresponding array in $_COOKIE. Instead use $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] as it mirrors the actual HTTP Request header.

Answer (score 0):

This could have various reasons. First of all, check if the cookie is set at all. Then make sure it uses the same parameters (except the expiration) as when the cookie was originally set. And for the expiration parameter, use a value that is definitely long in the past (one hour could be too little if your server’s time is off by some hours):

```
setcookie($cookieName, 'deleted', 1, $cookiePath, $cookieDomain);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple tutorial about delete cookie by php
first we set the cookie value and expire date.

```
setcookie('test', 'test', time() + 3600);
```

visit the page, you'll see the cookie 'test' has successfully created

then, we change the php code to delete cookie 'test', just set a passed date value for it

```
setcookie('test', 'test', time() - 3600);
```

visit the page again, you'll find the cookie 'test' has gone

btw: i was use the fire cookie extension to check the cookie value.

hope this simple tutorial can help you.